# Find sets of elements in a list, elements can only be used once - How to approach algorithm

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, recursion, set

I have the following list

```
Cards: [B1 G1 O1 R1 G2 G3 R4]
Sets:  [G1 G2 G3]
Sets:  [B1 G1 O1 R1]
```

A set can be cards of the same color, but sequential
or cards that are the same value, but different color

I'm reaching the end of my sorting algorithm and here is where I am having trouble.

The goal is to play as many cards as possible. The AI I created can find sets. My problem here is I'm not sure how I can use an algorithm to help the AI make a good decision.

If it play the biggest `Set[B1 G1 O1 R1]` first then it will not be able to play the `Set[G1 G2 G3]`.

Of course if it plays the `set[G1 G2 G3]` first, then it will be able to play `[B1 O1 R1]`

When I reach a list this small. how can I calculate the best path for the AI to take? Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Sounds like the "Set Cover Problem" which is well known. If the number of sets is small, a brute force search of all combinations would be quite feasible. Algorithms to enumerate all combinations are also well known.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find best combinations that use up the most elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951123/algorithm-to-find-best-combinations-that-use-up-the-most-elements-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that blows up exponentially, so it will only work for a small list of cards. It may be adequate for you, or it may point the way to a better solution, so I thought I'd write it up.

Create a graph, the nodes of which are the sets that can be made. So in your case the nodes are:

```
{G1,G2,G3} {G1,G2} {G2,G3} {B1,G1,O1,R1} {B1,G1,O1} {B1,G1,R1}, {B1,O1,R1} {G1,O1,R1} {B1,G1} {B1,O1} {B1,R1} {G1,O1} {G1,R1} {O1,R1}
```

Now join two nodes with an edge if those two sets are compatible choices, i.e., they have no intersection. So the edges in your graph are

```
{G1,G2,G3} -- {B1,O1,R1} 
{G1,G2,G3} -- {B1,O1}
{G1,G2,G3} -- {B1,R1}
{G1,G2,G3} -- {O1,R1}
{G1,G2} -- {B1,O1,R1}
{G1,G2} -- {B1,O1}
{G1,G2} -- {B1,R1}
{G1,G2} -- {O1,R1}
{G2,G3} -- everything after it
{B1,G1,O1,R1} -- nothing after it 
same for all the 3 element subsets from there on 
{B1,G1} -- {O1,R1} 
{B1,O1} -- {G1,R1} 
{B1,R1} -- {G1,O1}
```

Your objective now is to find maximal cliques in that graph, where a clique is a mutually compatible set ... there is an edge between every pair of nodes in a clique. There are libraries you can use to find maximal cliques, but it more or less boils down to a brute force search (CLIQUE is NP-hard). A library will at least save you some typing. In fact, what you want is a maximum clique, where the value of a clique is the sum of the node weights, where the weight of a node is the number of elements in the set corresponding to the node. A clique library will find maximum cliques for you.

There's probably a better way, but that's what I've got for now.